# write a loop to represent each polynomial from an array for n polynomials

Tags: python, function, loops, variable-assignment

```
import csv
import numpy
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import json

reader=csv.reader(open("/Users/61/Desktop/pythonlearning/generator1.csv","rU"),delimiter=',')
a=list(reader)
result=numpy.array(a)
print a 

b = []
for n in range(3):
    b.append(a[n+1][0:3])
print b
e = np.array(b)
f = e.astype(np.float)
print f

x = Symbol("x")
y = Symbol("y")

coeffs = f
F1 = numpy.poly1d(f[0])
F12 = np.polyder(F1)
print F12
F2 = numpy.poly1d(f[1])
F22 = np.polyder(F2)
print F22
F3 = numpy.poly1d(f[2])
F32 = np.polyder(F3) 
print F32
```

this is my coding and f is a array of numbers like this:`[[  9.68000000e-04   6.95000000e+00   7.49550000e+02]
 [  7.38000000e-04   7.05100000e+00   1.28500000e+03] [  1.04000000e-03   6.53100000e+00   1.53100000e+03]]`.
Basically, I want to assign the value of `f` to form polynomials, and then differentiate the polynomials. The results it like this `0.001936 x + 6.95  0.001476 x + 7.051  0.00208 x + 6.531`
My question is how could write a loop for Fn if instead of 3 polynomials, I have n polynomials instead. How could I write a loop to obtain the differentiation for the n polynomials and can easy use the polynomials with different name of it. eg, F1 represent the first polynomial and F2 represent the second and so on.
 i tried sth like this, but it doesnt work

```
i = 1
if i < 3:
    F(i)=numpy.poly1d(f[i-1])
else:
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're importing `numpy` 3 times? Use a single `import numpy as np` statement, and prefix all of the calls to that library with `np.`. It's bad form to use `from lib_name import *` for large, complex libraries like `numpy` and `sympy` (or, arguably, any library) into the current namespace, which is what you're doing with the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop to deal with a variable number of polynomials and a data structure to store them. Try using a dictionary, iterating using a for loop.

```
numberPolynomials = 3
F = {}
for n in range(1, numberPolynomials+1):
    F[n] = np.poly1d(f[n-1])
    F[(n, 2)] = np.polyder(F[n])
    print F[(n, 2)]
```

Now you can refer to the polynomial not as `F1`, `F2`, etc. but as `F[1]`, `F[2]`, etc. For what you had called `F12`, `F22`, `F32` would then be `F[(1,2)]`, `F[(2,2)]`, `F[(3,2)]`. Though, if you aren't going to be using the originals you should overwrite them and probably just use a list.

This is assuming, you change the 3x imports of numpy to:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, after using your strategy, I could not use the equation represents by F[(1,2)], F[(2,2)], F[(3,2)] for further steps. for instance, when I print F[(1,2)], F[(2,2)], F[(3,2)] separately, it does not give the desired value.